# Nginx. Get full request uri

Tags: php, nginx

Is there any ability to get full request URI from Nginx?
For example I would like to obtain characters like `?` and `#` from the URI.

My example Nginx configuration file (some not important parts is omitted):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.dev;

  root /srv/http/test/public;
  index index.php;

  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

My index.php:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';die;
```

I use such URL to test `http://test.dev/"A / \\ \f b ? c.@mail.com`.

Actual output:

```
Array
(
    [_url] => /"A / \\ \f b 
    [c_@mail_com] => 
)
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [_url] => /"A / \\ \f b ? c.@mail.com
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't `$request` [variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request) what you need?

Comment: Hmm.. `$request` is broken if I use `#` in uri like `"A / \\ \f b ? # c.@msd$f0&8*.==`

Comment: @klay What do you mean broken? Hashtag and the contents after it is never transmitted to server. It's a part of HTTP specification and is a normal behavior.

Comment: result `"A / \\ \f b ? ` instead `"A / \\ \f b ? # c.@msd$f0&8*.==`

Comment: Now i try to use php's `base64_encode` / `base64_decode` as workaround. For my small RESTful "Email cleaner & validator": http://i.imgur.com/Ptnf6rj.png

Comment: `$request` variable does not exist

Comment: $request variable containts the full rquest including method and so on. Its not really the full url.